# I'm getting symbol _cilk_spawn could not be resolved when compiling with icpc

Tags: c++, icc, cilk

Im using Ubuntu 14.04 & eclipse & intel compiler v 15

I have 2 same programs (which use cilk commands) (one with as c program and the other as cpp program).

I can compile it with icc (without any problem)

But when I'm using icpc (cpp program) I'm getting errors: symbol _cilk_spawn could not be resolved

In those same 2 programs Im not using any flags.

What is the different with cpp program, which I cant compile it

Comment: Can you create a minimal example that reproduces the problem along with the compiler commands to compile it?

Comment: if I compile it without eclipse, the command is: icc myExample.c (simple, without any flags)

Answer (score 1):

The keyword is "_Cilk_spawn", with a capital "C". The C/C++ convention is for non-standard extensions to have a leading underscore and start with a capital letter.

You can also include cilk.h which defines macros to allow you to use "cilk_spawn", "cilk_sync" and "cilk_for".